# Assembly/MIPS: branching

Tags: assembly, branch, mips

I'm trying to compare two numbers using branching. Using a youtube video I tried to learn branching but the video doesn't explain what happens when the condition is false. My program is running both of the labels instead of the branch that is true.
My program is as follows:

```
#branch if equal 
.data 

message: .asciiz "The numbers are equal."
message2: .asciiz "The numbers are differnet."

.text

main:
    #set temp regs t0 and t1 to 5 and 20 respectively 
    addi $t0, $zero, 5 
    addi $t1, $zero, 21 

    #if t0 and t1 are eaual, branch to label numbersEqual
    beq $t0, $t1, numbersEqual
    #if t0 and t1 are not equal, branch to label numbersDifferent
    bne $t0, $t1, numbersDifferent

    #Syscall to end program 
    li  $v0, 10 
    syscall


numbersDifferent: #syscall to retrieve message and print text   
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, message2
    syscall

numbersEqual: #syscall to retrieve message and print text 
    li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, message 
    syscall
```

Comment: Of course it does, if it branches to `numbersDifferent` it prints a message, and then it prints the other message, and then it doesn't actually exit cleanly. You have apparently made no attempt to avoid this situation..

Comment: It's pretty useless to read a book on cooking if you don't have a kitchen, isn't it? :) The same applies to programming, you first steps should be aimed at 1) how do I execute something and 2) how do I debug it. Both can be accomplished with a simulator like [SPIM](http://spimsimulator.sourceforge.net/) or [MARS](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/). They will let you see how the CPU executes each instruction, step by step.

Comment: @harold 'apparently' you could have simply stated that i needed to call for an exit label. some people are learning this on their own and don't have the resources to get though problems like this efficiently'...'